# SSAS Show value but exclude from hierarchy aggregation

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

how can I exclude members of a hierarchy with a certain attribute-value from the aggregation?
The thing is, the value should be shown anyway.

Example:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92hC3.png)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the MDX Script (Calculations tab and script view):

```
([Your Dimension].[Your Member].[All], [Your Dimension].[Your Attribute].[All]) = ([Your Dimension].[Your Member].[All], [Your Dimension].[Your Attribute].[All]) - ([Your Dimension].[Your Member].[All], [Your Dimension].[Your Attribute].&[%]);
```

Comment: This didnt work. Solved it by adding another column with a unary operator.

Comment: @Quip I suspect if your question had been a little less vague then Greg would have been able to help. Please can you add your answer so future users are able to use what you have discovered.